# How to completely uninstall django-taggit from my project?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I want to remove [django-taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) from my project, but when I removed the `'taggit'` app from the `INSTALLED_APPS`, the following error occurred:

```
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration SourceManager.0002_auto_20190218_2112 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('taggit', '0002_auto_20150616_2121')
```

I think this error occurred because django-taggit has migration files, so how to safely remove it from my project?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way, other than manually editing the older migration files to remove all references to taggit. If you do it correctly, it shouldn't cause any harm as long as you won't go back to any point where you need them to run correctly.

Comment: Will this is bad news.

Answer (score 1):

You are half way through. The django-taggit has migration files and that's why you are facing the error.

You may want to reset the database state and re-apply the migrations to avoid this error.

[This tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) explains in detail how to reset the database and re-apply the migrations. I suggest you to follow the procedure step by step.

**A word of caution:** Even if you are a Unix bases OS user, **avoid** deleting migration files by executing the commands given in tutorial. The command messes up with Django default files and creates unncessary problems. Better to delete migration files one-by-one and model-by-model.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a less aggressive solution.

Comment: Haven’t done it myself but here’s another suggestion: before removing taggit itself, squash your migrations. This will remove all references to taggit in the squashed migration. Make sure the squashed migration is applied to all databases you have. Then you can delete old migration files. And remove taggit. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) for detailed instructions.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb: I'm afraid but there is no less aggressive solution to this. If you want to remove the dependency which is there in migrations, you have to take manual steps. It is not that aggressive anyway if you know what you are doing.